# How to handle inter-dependency/ circular dependency in Visual Studio(C++11)

Tags: c++, class, circular-dependency

I'm trying to create header and class files for two interdependent classes. I tried using `#pragma once`, `extern` class declaration, declaring classes in each other's headers. None of them seem to work. Here's my sample code:

> A.h

```
#pragma once
#include "B.h"

class A
{
    private:
        int num;
    public:
        A();
        void printB(B b);
        int getA();
        ~A();
};
```

> A.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "A.h"
#include <iostream>


A::A()
{
    num = 5;
}

void A::printB(B b)
{
    std::cout << "b = " << b.getB()  << std::endl;
}

int A::getA()
{
    return num;
}

A::~A()
{
}
```

> B.h

```
#pragma once
#include "A.h"
class B
{
    private:
        char ch;
    public:
        B();
        void printA(A a);
        char getB();
        ~B();
};
```

> B.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "B.h"


B::B()
{
    ch = 'g';
}

void B::printA(A a)
{
    std::cout << "a = " << a.getA() << std::endl;
}

char B::getB()
{
    return ch;
}

B::~B()
{
}
```

> Interedependency.cpp [Entry point/ Main file]

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "A.h"


int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    a.printB(b);
    b.printA(a);
    return 0;
}
```

How to handle such interdependent classes in Visual Studio?

Comment: i think you should look at forward declaring a class instead of including the header e.g. class B; class A { ... }; then in a.cpp include "b.h"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Comment: This has nothing to do with visual studio, it's a C++ question (not even c++11).

Comment: `#pragma once` is only useful for header (cpp file are not included).

Answer (score 0):

Don't include `A.h` or `B.h` in your headers, instead, forward declare `A` in `B.h` and `B` in `A.h`.
In your cpp files, include `A.h` from `B.cpp` and `B.h` from `A.cpp`.

In `A.h` - replace `#include "B.h"` with `class A;` - this tells the compiler we'll be using the class `A`, but we'll provide the details later.
The compiler only cares for class sizes at this point (in your case).
In the cpp file, include `B.h` to actually tell the compiler what `B` is all about, as you're going to actually use it.
Do the same for `B.h` and `B.cpp` - replacing the include with a forward declaration in the header, and including the other header in the source file.

Additionally, there is no need for `#pragma once` in the cpp files, these are already compiled once.